# How to use Jekyll locally to create/edit posts on remote WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, markdown, jekyll

How do I use Jekyll on my local machine to create/edit posts on my remote WordPress blog? More specifically:

- I want to write posts in plain text, use Jekyll's markup parser to create HTML, and then post the resulting HTML to my WordPress site.
- If I edit an existing local text file, I want the corresponding WordPress post edited. I don't care if revision history is preserved on WordPress, since I plan on preserving it locally.

Rationale: I really like the idea of having a website stored/generated locally and then mirrored to a server, in part because that was the *only* way to do things when I first started posting to the Web.

However, I feel Jekyll's lack of comments, trackbacks, and server-side scripting (though JavaScript may suffice) are not *quite* sufficient for my needs, especially since I want to avoid using third party tools such as Disqus, or even a local version of Disqus that runs in parallel to my blog.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you look into the source code used to generate your static files, the Theme in other-words. In the case of Minima that would be the [`_layouts`](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/tree/master/_layouts) and [`_includes`](https://github.com/jekyll/minima/tree/master/_includes) directories for what's *building* most of the templated HTML. Then look into Jekyll's [*`Usage`*](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/) and [*`Configs`*](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/), specifically the `--destination` option I think you'll find helpful in targeting a sub-directory within your WordPress site's folder structure.

Getting the *look-n-feel* to be consistent between pages generated by Jekyll and those built with WordPress is likely to be more than a little *fiddly*. CSS loading properly, just to name one future issue I believe you'll face. But using the `base_url` setting within either the main `_config.yml` or a [`_config_baseurl.yml`](https://github.com/S0AndS0/Jekyll_Admin/blob/gh-pages/_config_baseurl.yml) (as I've done for my own non-WordPress related project), might allow for bodging something that gets what ya want done.

I'm not suggesting that you pursue hybridizing Jekyll and WordPress, but I think the easiest route will be building to a sub-directory within your WordPress site. However, do be careful as the default `jekyll build` process removes anything within the `--destination` directory!

Now if your aim is instead to use server-side scripting within Jekyll built pages (first, how perverse... in a good way...), it would be a good idea to keep file types in mind, eg. `.md`/`.markdown` files are *tab-sensitive* and will have angle-brackets (`<` and `>`), among other things parsed through *`smartify`*. So doing something like...

```
---
layout: post
title: Jekyll with PHP test
---

<?php

    echo "Hello World!"

?>


Stuff about things regarding `PHP` and Jekyll
```

... would, if I remember correctly, output something like...

---

<?php

```
echo "Hello World!"
```

?>

Stuff about things regarding `PHP` and Jekyll

---

... because the `<?php` got translated into `&lt;?php`, the `echo "Hello World!"` turned into a code-block, and `?>` was transmuted into `?&gt;`

Not a *good time*, so if you must do stuff like that for some reason I'll suggest that you make use of Liquid's `raw` tags, eg....

```
{% raw %}
<?php

    echo "Hello World!"

?>
{% endraw %}
```

... to prevent *`smartify`* from getting *clever* with what you maybe trying to do.

If you could be more specific as to what things you'd need replaced to make a full switch to Jekyll, perhaps others or future revisions of this answer will include more suggestions on that tangent. For now I did see that GitHub has launched [`Team Discussions`](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-team-discussions) and I've heard rumors of those that use `Issues` almost like a forum.

As for keeping things synced/*mirrored* between local edits and your remote server, it might be worth looking into `git aliases` and `git hooks`, as these may be leveraged for doing things in addition to, or intermixed with, other Git operations.